# PHP PDO execute insert into db not working and dont know why

Tags: php, pdo, insert

```
  $q = "INSERT INTO accounts (from_bank, from_user, to_user, amount, date_time, notes) VALUES (:from_bank, :from_user, :to_user, :amount, :date_time, :notes)";
    $query = $db->prepare($q);
    $result = $query->execute(array(
        ":from_bank" => $from_bank,
        ":from_user" => $from_user,
        ":to_user" => $to_user, 
        ":amount" => $amount,
        ":date_time" => $date_time,
        ":notes" => $notes
    ));
```

Ok this has been solved (cant answer my own question until level 8 currently im level 6) it was an unrelated line to do with `$date_time = 'now()';` it was originally missing single quotes and now it works as it should I cant believe it didnt have any errors even tho I tryed using a try to catch any errors any ideas why this error wasnt caught?

Comment: Do you have error repoting and displaying enabled?

Comment: I have no errors displaying and i have not turnt them off, the error reporting is on by default and in my connect.php file i have defined my db vars and also have these 2 lines $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,$db_username,$db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

Answer (score 2):

in pdo you don't put single quotes around your parameters:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO accounts (from_bank, from_user, to_user, amount, date_time, notes) VALUES (:from_bank, :from_user, :to_user, :amount, :date_time, :notes)";
```

also here's a link to a tutorial you might find very useful:

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers